# Create a category menu using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am making my first steps coding. I made some courses in Lynda.com, Treehouse and then CodeAcademy.

Today I decided to start building a wordpress theme so like this I could continue learning from the practice.

I made a child theme of the twentyfifteen theme that allows me to use a dropdown main menu in the side bar.

I started watching how to make my menu structure and now I have this problem:

I know that I can create a menu like this:

```
Page 1
   Subpage 1A 
   Subpage 1B
   Subpage 1C
Page 2
   Subpage 2A 
   Subpage 2B
   Subpage 2C
Page 3
   Subpage 3A 
   Subpage 3B
   Subpage 3C
```

It's simple I can create some pages and add another pages inside them in the menu.

But to make these subpages is necessary to create a page, something clickable, something with content. what I am trying to do is to have page 1, page 2 and page 3 as a category, as the title of their groups. So if you make click on them it will not link you to a template, it only will to open the dropdown of subpages. It is something possible to make in the menu settings in wordpress?

do you have some suggestion? Thank you very much it would help a lot in my research.

Comment: You should learn about [Wordpress taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Comment: Thank you @vard I didn't know that it was called taxonomy. I will read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parent items (Page 1, Page 2, etc) as Custom Links and put # instead of URL. Save, after that you can remove # and save again. This should do the trick.